# Python/SqlAlchemy: Binding attributes (100s) to Base sub-classes sensibly

Tags: python, database, class, sqlite, sqlalchemy

My project involves data-wrangling some government form filings. I have a decade of filings, about a dozen sections per year, in the form of CSV. Each CSV is paired with a file with the field names, types, and sizes. Since the data is originally from a relational DB of some sort, I figured the most sensible way to handle the data is pop it into Sqlite and use SqlAlchemy to query it.

I'm just getting my feet wet with SqlAlchemy and it seems the typical way of creating database objects is to create a class with a Column attribute for each field, as such:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    ...
```

and then access rows from the table with something like

```
person = session.query(Person).filter(Person.name == 'bob').all()
```

However, there are over a hundred of these such tables, and some tables have upwards of 150 fields. Yikes, not coding that by hand. I wrote a quick script to generate the .py file from the list of fields, which works, but feels a bit un-pythonic.

It seems like from [some examples](http://pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) I need to pass the **class**, not the **instance**, but I could be missing some nuance here. I tried binding attributes using setattr to a base class, but after some mucking with factory functions and mangling inheritance in various ways, it was clear python's type management was not going to play ball. The only other thing that comes to mind is trying messing around with class instances and deepcopy, but that also seems dodgy.

Is there a nice/elegant way of creating a hundred declarative_base subclasses with a hundred fields from a template, or more importantly, is there a better way in general of interfacing with these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the SQLAlchemy's Table API directly and specify the tables column types more generically (with variation) rather than use the more verbose declarative API.

```
for scary in scary_gov_data:

  t = Table(scary['name'], metadata,
      Column('col1', Integer, primary_key=True),
      Column('col2', String(16), nullable=False))
```

What you really need to be thinking about is probably less how you use the SQLAlchemy API and more whether the resulting database schema is going to be effective for the query strategies you will have to be executing on it.

For example there is nothing wrong per se with a SQL table that has 150 columns but it could cause issues if you don't think ahead to how that data is going to be queried.

As far as using SQLAlchemy goes, it sounds like you don't want to be touching the ORM features for this project because you are dealing more with the raw data challenges and the ORM will likely complicate things. Luckily, part of SQLAlchemy's magic is that it's ORM is built on top of an outstanding low-level SQL interface-- essentially allowing you to write pretty close to plain SQL queries using Python functions.

I hope this is helpful, feel free to clarify if it is not.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the input! I will be trying things out with the table api.

I feel you about the schema thing. I'm still working that part out, so far about 70% of my time has gone into studying, experimenting with, and trying to understand the data structures. Which is a little more than I budgeted for, but this is my first real delve into non-numeric data work.

Comment: Glad to help, best of luck.